# Solution for 2nd order DE when characteristic equation has non-conjugate roots

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The solution for 2nd order DE with complex conjugate chracteristic roots of $a \pm ib$ is well known. What if a DE has characteristic roots 
$r_1 = a + ib$ and $r_2 = -a - ib$? What is the general form of the solution for the DE in this case?

Or does this even satisfy the condition for linear independence so that a solution does not exist?

Comment: It will still be a linear combination $A_1e^{r_1t}+A_2e^{r_2t}$ with complex coefficients, that's all. A remark: I have never met such a type of equation in practice.

Comment: Thank you for your help, see LutzL's answer below for the DE I was dealing with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the linear ODE with constant coefficients is real, then its roots have to follow the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra. All complex roots come in complex-conjugate pairs. Thus if you have a root $-a-bi$, then you also have a root $-a+ib$ and thus in total 4 roots, which is not possible for a second order ODE.

The second order ODE with roots $a+ib$ and $-a-ib$ is 
$$
0=y''-(a+ib)^2y=y''-(a^2-b^2+2iab)y
$$
and will have complex coefficients in all non-trivial cases.

Comment: Thank you, exactly that $y'' - (a + ib)^2 y = 0$ was my ODE. So the general solution will be the normal $A_1 e^{r_1t} + A_2 e^{r_2t}$ as stated above by JeanMarie.

Comment: Yes, if the equation is not real, then the solution is a combination of exponentials with no preferred form.